# Illustrator to Coreo

Tags: adobe-illustrator, plugin, autocad

We just purchased a Multicam flatbed cutter about 6 months ago. It uses Coreo software and I am the graphic designer. I create our files in Illustrator, then I send the .ai file to the machinist to open in Coreo for cutting.

It has worked most of the time and we have found some solutions for issues here and there, but lately, it's becoming more inconsistent in cutting corners smoothly. It appears that even when the corner looks good on screen, it just doesn't read the radius correctly. I have since started researching the issue and it appears Illustrator isn't as compatible with CAD as it should be, even if I saved the files as .dxf.

So my question is: is there a plugin for Illustrator or another conversion software I can use to create proper arcs and lines without having to purchase AutoCAD? Is there a way in Coreo to convert?

What I am finding is that Illustrator creates polylines but the cutter reads arcs/lines or splines. So is there any easy solution to this? attached is an image of what the corner looks like in Illustrator and then what it looks like after converting it to the cutter.

[image: Screenshot of a sharp corner radius in Illustrator]

[image: Screenshot of a poorly rendered corner radius in Coreo]

Comment: I dont think there is a good solution. There is nothing really wrong with the dxf files illustrator makes. Its just that the primitives illustrator has to work with are a bit bad for the general cad application because you cant make an actual circular arc in illustrator. You should probably invest in Rhino

Comment: I guess you see AutoCAD as a possible environment to create the wanted drawings. Check if you can accept some free 2D CAD program. Some of them have paid much attention to handle AutoCAD formats (which have been updated numerous times to keep low cost and free rivals one step behind). One such free program is 10 years old IMSI DoubleCAD XT v5, but it's still available and works at least in WIN10. It knows splines and circular arcs and exports them properly in DXF files. See an export option screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f2Nx.png